# Save jq into variable script bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

The main objective of this script is to download the following URL

```
https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=(varGameId)
```

For this reason I need to get the gameId of NBA Games that I get with this format.

```
$(cat 00_todays_scores.json | jq '.gs.g['$COUNTER'].gid')
```

The steps of the complete Script

1 - Create a folder with the day

2 - Go to the folder created before

3 -Download the scores of today

4 - Get the total games of today with jq .length

5 -Loop to iterate the total games of the days.

My poblem is that I don't know how to pass this gamesId getting here into variable String.

```
 $(cat 00_todays_scores.json | jq '.gs.g['$COUNTER'].gid')
```

The complete script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-----Starting download-----"
mkdir /home/user/Desktop/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
cd /home/user/Desktop/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
wget https://data.nba.com/data/10s/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2017/scores/00_todays_scores.json
longitudNBAGamesDay=$(cat 00_todays_scores.json | jq '.gs.g | length')
restar=1;
total=$(($longitudNBAGamesDay-$restar))
cd /home/usuario/Desktop/$(date +"%m-%d-%y")  
COUNTER=0
while [  $COUNTER -lt $total ]; do
mkdir $(cat 00_todays_scores.json | jq '.gs.g['$COUNTER'].gid')
let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```

Regards ! :)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do or where you are having trouble. To what extent does the script as written do what you want and what is missing?

Comment: @Mort I try to explain better now.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: BTW, `cat foo | bar` is less efficient than `bar <foo` or its equally-valid equivalent `<foo bar`. Sometimes **much** less efficient, if `bar` is something that can parallelize by having different threads or subprocesses reading from different parts of the input file at the same time (which can't be done with a pipeline from an external tool such as `cat`, since pipelines can only be read once, front-to-back).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just a quoting issue that you're having. Two things:

1. variables will only be interpolated inside `"` double-quotes. Inside single-quotes it will just be seen as the string literal "`$COUNTER`".
2. bash will not interpret your quoting as outer- and inner-quoting, but as two pairs.

The following should fix both. (Don't worry about the apparent single-quoes around $COUNTER. Bash only sees the double-quotes. By the time it gets to `jq`, the variable has already been interpolated and it's fin in single-quotes.)

```
while [  $COUNTER -lt $total ]; do
    mkdir $(cat 00_todays_scores.json | jq ".gs.g['$COUNTER'].gid")
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```

(Though I don't know enough about `jq` to know if its syntax is correct at all.)

Comment: It's not good practice. `jq`, like `awk`, lets variables be passed out-of-band from code.

Comment: Thus, just like correct use of shell variables in awk is `awk -v var="$value" '...code...'`, correct use of `jq` is `jq --argjson counter "$COUNTER" '.gs.g[$counter].gid'`, **if** one were going to retrieve only one gid at a time, which is silly.

Comment: (Also, for a numeric index, there shouldn't be literal quotes in the expression).

Comment: ...btw, while I suggested `--argjson` above, one could also use `--arg counter_str "$COUNTER"` and then inside the `jq` code use `.gs.g[($counter | tonumber)].gid` -- which is a little more cautious, since it's not letting the counter be parsed as any non-numeric type.

Comment: All great points @CharlesDuffy. I was looking at the micro-issues that the poster was asking, not the macro-issues of the whole script.

Comment: (err, my most recent suggestion should have been `($counter_str | tonumber)` above, since I changed the name to reflect the string type being used)

Answer (score 0):

Why retrieve only one GID at a time?

```
# with bash 4.0 or newer
readarray -t gids < <(jq -r '.gs.g[].gid' <00_todays_scores.json)
```

...will put all your GIDs into a single bash array (if you have bash 4.0 or newer).

With bash 3.x, that instead would look like:

```
# doesn't require bash 4.0; passes through invalid exit status if jq doesn't succeed
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a gids \
  < <(jq -r '.gs.g[].gid' <00_todays_scores.json && printf '\0')
```

---

Either way, you can print that array as follows:

```
declare -p gids
```

...or iterate through it with:

```
for gid in "${gids[@]}"; do
  echo "Retrieved a gid: $gid"
done
```

...or pass every element it contains to a single invocation of `mkdir` with:

```
mkdir -p -- "${gids[@]}"
```